# Select other attributes from minimum rows in cross join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm writing a query that joins many locations with a list of transit stations, it order to determine the minimum distance to a public transit stop. With query is fairly simple:

```
select
  location.id,
  MIN(
    ST_distance_sphere(
      ST_MakePoint(
        transit.latitude,
        transit.longitude
      ),
      ST_MakePoint(
        cast(locations.latitude as double precision),
        cast(locations.longitude as double precision)
      )
    )
  ) as meters_from_nearest_stop,
from public.transit_stops transit
cross join public.locations locations
group by 1
```

This, however, can not naively give me the location with the minimum distance, just the minimum distance. How can I modify this to return me other attributes from the row with the minimum distance?

The resulting cross join is fairly large, so performance is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done with the row_number() function like so:

```
select *, 
    row_number() over (partition by location.id order by meters_from_nearest_stop) as closest
from (
    select
      location.id,
      transit.id,
      ST_distance_sphere(
          ST_MakePoint(
            transit.latitude,
            transit.longitude
          ),
          ST_MakePoint(
            cast(locations.latitude as double precision),
            cast(locations.longitude as double precision)
          )
        )
      as meters_from_nearest_stop,
    from public.transit_stops transit
    cross join public.locations locations
) q
where closest=1
```

Comment: Glad to help @StevenWright. If it answered the question, don't forget to accept the answer to close it off.